# Hiding the button clicked inside a repeater using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a repeater with a couple of controls in it, one of which is a LinkButton called lbtn_reconfirm.

What I'm trying to do is to hide only the lbtn_reconfirm clicked using JavaScript. I should say that the repeater is inside a Formview called fv_Contract. Having a hard time getting the control's ID in order to perform the hide.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptr_1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptr_1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtn_reconfirm" runat="server" CssClass="col-lg-6" Text="Reconfirm" OnClick="lbtn_reconfirm_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ScheduleID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        <hr />
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <div id="noRecords" runat="server" visible="false">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">No schedules have been assigned.</div>
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: It can be done, but it has no purpose. If you press the button and hide it with javascript, it will be shown again on PostBack because the hidden state is not sent to the server. So better set the visibility from code behind.

Comment: Do onclick="doSomething(this);" then hide it in doSomething(this) function. BUT this will show the button again on refresh. you can set the visibility to false in doSomething function also. but you should call by onServerClick and the function should be in backend

Comment: VDWWD - In this instance, that will actually be OK

Answer (score -1):

You can add `onclick` handler to the button with the following code

```js
document.getElementById('lbtn_reconfirm').onclick = function hide() {
   document.getElementById('lbtn_reconfirm').style = "visiblity: hidden";
}
```

Comment: First, `lbtn_reconfirm` does not exist because the controls are in a Repeater. Second, as stated in my comment, the PostBack will remove javascript changes immediately.